# Why if [ false ]; then echo 'ok'; fi; prints ok?

Tags: linux, bash

Why when I type in bash: `if [ false ]; then echo 'ok'; fi;` I get `ok` string as a result? The similiar result I can get also when using variable: `ok=false; if [ $ok ]; then echo 'ok'; fi;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`if [ false ]` is equivalent to `if [ -n "false" ]` - it's testing the length of the string. If you are trying to test the exit code of `/bin/false`, use `if false` (no `[`, which for many, but not all, modern shells is a shell builtin roughly equivalent to `/usr/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/test`).

Comment: This explains it better than the other answers, but `[` is going to be the builtin command, not the external binary.

Comment: @jordanm True for some shells, but not all... Although, I guess, the OP was tagged with `bash` for which `[` is internal... Clarified the answer a bit, regardless.

Answer (score 3):

`true` and `false` are not builtin keywords for boolean in bash the same way they are for other programming languages

You can simulate the test of true / false condition of a variable as follows:

```
cond1="true"
cond2="false"

if [ "$cond1" = "true" ]; then
    echo "First condition is true"
fi

if [ "$cond2" = "false" ]; then
    echo "Second condition is false"
fi
```

When you are doing:

```
if [ false ]
```

It implicitly translates to

```
if [ -n "false" ]
```

Where the `-n` denotes "test if this has length greater than 0: logically true if so, logically false otherwise"

Aside - `true` and `false` actually do do something, but they are commands:

```
man true
man false
```

To read more about them.